# SQL - Counts not returning zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this query which selects a few fields from one table and returns counts from some other tables.

My problem: if one of my counter fields counts zero, it doesn't return the number 0, it's just blank - which is what I would like to try and solve.

```
SELECT mem.member_id, mem.screen_name, mem.firstname, mem.lastname, mem.country_code, 
mem.joined, rep.rep as reputation, com.cnt as comments FROM members AS mem
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT member_id, SUM(awarded_what) as rep
    FROM members_reputation
    GROUP BY member_id) rep
    ON mem.member_id = rep.member_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT member_id, COUNT(comment_id) as cnt
    FROM blog_comments
    GROUP BY comment_id) com
    ON mem.member_id = com.member_id
GROUP BY mem.member_id
ORDER BY mem.joined DESC
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
Screen Name      | Comments
-----------------|--------------------
marty76          | 0
jonnyBoy12       | 0
adamApple        | 12
```

But, I'm getting something like this instead!

```
Screen Name      | Comments
-----------------|--------------------
marty76          | 
jonnyBoy12       | 
adamApple        | 12
```

Using my server side language this is easily fixed, by replacing null values with a zero. But I would like to have the zeros coming straight from SQL so I can order by the counts.

Any suggestions would be marvelous.

Comment: There's no need for the derived tables -- correct the joins, and your problem is solved.

Comment: @OMGPonies:  I removed 5 other LEFT OUTER JOIN counts from this query so it read easier for my question. Do you still mean what you said? I tested derived tables against other methods and this won in performance, by far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [**IFNULL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) Function

```
SELECT mem.member_id, mem.screen_name, mem.firstname, mem.lastname, mem.country_code,  
mem.joined, rep.rep as reputation, IFNULL(com.cnt,0) as comments FROM members AS mem 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT member_id, SUM(awarded_what) as rep 
    FROM members_reputation 
    GROUP BY member_id) rep 
    ON mem.member_id = rep.member_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT member_id, COUNT(comment_id) as cnt 
    FROM blog_comments 
    GROUP BY comment_id) com 
    ON mem.member_id = com.member_id 
GROUP BY mem.member_id 
ORDER BY mem.joined DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Rolando, that's a great help.

Comment: That answer has actually helped me with other queries. I now know I can do this: IFNULL(column,"N/A"), which allows me to remove a bit of server side code in a few places. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
COUNT(comment_id)
```

to

```
IFNULL(COUNT(comment_id), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

other way could be :

```
 coalesce(count(comment_id),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should give you the results you're trying to get and it is much simpler than your query:

```
SELECT mem.member_id, mem.screen_name, mem.firstname, mem.lastname,
  mem.country_code, mem.joined,
  SUM(awarded_what) reputation, COUNT(comment_id) comments
FROM members mem
LEFT JOIN members_reputation rep ON mem.member_id = rep.member_id
LEFT JOIN blog_comments com ON mem.member_id = com.member_id
GROUP BY mem.member_id
ORDER BY mem.joined DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't perform as well as my derived table method. In my real query, I have 7 left outer join counts coming from multiple tables. Testing against 10 DB records, my query runs in 0ms, your query runs in 1ms - over 1m records and this is a considerable performance gain. Thanks tho :)

Comment: Testing agains 10 db records is no testing at all. Test it many times with at least 10,000 records on each table. The 1 ms difference could even be a simple StackOverflow webpage refresh that generated a context switch at that time. This can't be slower as it is doing less work than you query

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 1ms difference being a StackOverflow webpage refresh. I'm testing the two queries in MySQL Workbench against my database and derived tables has won. It has nothing to do with a StackOverflow website refresh! When I say 10 record testing, I mean 10 record limit on my query as that is all I am printing to screen in my app. There are 1000's of comments that it counts through.

Comment: +1: I was about to post this.  IME, derived tables are more work but more to the point of the question -- COUNT only counts non-NULL values, so this will return zero where there are no supporting records.  The derived table approach still requires the use of IFNULL or COALESCE to handle NULLs.  Then, there's the issue of [MySQL's handling hidden columns in the GROUP BY...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Answer (score -2):

Could you use ISNULL?

```
ISNULL(com.cnt, 0) as comments
```